# why am i not getting output when I make "j<0" at line 1 in a below code?

Tags: java, loops, variables

when I make "j<=0" output is shown, but why am I not getting when I make "j<0" at line 1.

```
public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     int i,j;

    for( i=0,j=0;i<3 & j<0;i++,j--)//line 1
    {

        System.out.println(i+"..."+j);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: when j-- is done..as j is decremented and its value becomes -1.

Comment: try initialising variables before the for loop

Comment: @Jonathan Laliberte, i have initialized to  i=0,j=0

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @chocksaway, trying to print  x and y values on a console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j < 0` means that `j` has to be smaller than 0, not equal. `j <= 0` is okay with equals.

For the loop to succeed `j < 0` has to be true but since `j` is initialized with value `0`, `j < 0` is not true, so the loop will basically just won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

because your condition by j<0 is always false. you are starting j from 0, so it will never be true to decrease j even for onetime.

Answer (score -1):

This code allows me to test your logic (i'm guessing that this is what you want to do) "correctly:"

```
public class Loop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (i < 3 && j < 0) {
                System.out.println(i + "..." + j);
            }
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
1...-1
2...-2
```

j is less than 0 (-1) when i is 1

j is less than 0 (-2) when i is 2

Comment: yes, it works according to above logic but when we take (i < 3 & j < 0) condition within a loop it fails, cause JVM checks initialised value along with the mentioned condition.here    j is initialized to zero and condition is  (i < 3 && j < 0) ,so it fails and loop terminates

Comment: I'm "guessing your logic".  I've included a complete example, with output (when run).  It is good practice to explain what you are trying to accomplish, with a code example.  I'm glad you've solved your problem.  Try following this approach for future questions you post.